# Why is libargtable behaving strangely with optional arguemnts?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, command-line-arguments

On the off-chance that anyone uses **argtable** as a **command line argument parser** for C-Code, here is my question:

## My Intention

I'm programming in C on a Linux platform using the most recent version of the argtable2 library.

What I want to archive is have a program that **takes multiple input files** and an **optional option** (let's call it `-o`). If `-o` is **not provided** as an option in a shell call, **no output is written by the program whatsoever**. If `-o` is **provided by itself** the program's output is **written to a default file** called "output.txt". If the option is **provided together with a file name**, e.g. `-o other.txt`, the **output should be written to the file name** that was given - in this case to "other.txt".

## The Problem

In all my tries **argtable misbehaved**. It **interprets the optional value** given along with `-o` **as an input file**. So `./program -o other.txt inputfile1.dat inputfile2.dat inputfile3.dat` would be interpreted as having four inputfiles - the three "inputfile*.dat"s and "other.txt" which is supposed to be the output file.

## Reproduce the problem

Here is a shell session to illustrate, what I mean. It uses a [minimal example](http://pastebin.com/LiLe7XMs) that produces the problem. I'm not sure if I did something wrong or if it is a bug in [libargtable2](http://argtable.sourceforge.net/):

```
confus@confusion:~$ gcc -o argbug argbug.c -largtable2
confus@confusion:~$ ./argbug
Error: missing option INPUT-FILES

Usage:
./argbug [-o [<file>]] INPUT-FILES
-o [<file>]               File to write output to. Default is 'output.txt'.
                         Omit whole option to discard all output
INPUT-FILES               Input files
confus@confusion:~$ ./argbug inputfile1.dat inputfile2.dat inputfile3.dat -o other.txt
inputfile[0] = inputfile1.dat              # this is okay output
inputfile[1] = inputfile2.dat              # as is this line
inputfile[2] = inputfile3.dat              # also okay output
inputfile[3] = other.txt                   # "other.txt" is falsely recognized as an input file
outputfile = output.txt                    # should be "other.txt" instead of the default "output.txt"
```

Either way neither I nor Steward, the author of argtable seem to have time to really look into my problem. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you requirements are ambiguous: how can the library decide whether you meant the filename after `-o` to be input or output? `-o input.txt` looks exactly as `-o output.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I  ran your test and found the same problem.  Looking into the source, it seems libargtable is handling it correctly, but it boils down to getopt behavior.

If you look beginning at line 647 in getopt.c, you can see that getopt first checks if there is an argument attached *without* any space in between the option and the argument (e.g. -oother.txt).  If that is the case, it handles it.  That is the only case in which it will notice an optional argument.

To test this, try

```
void *argtable[] = { argOutput, end };
```

in your testcase, and then

```
./argbug -o other.txt
```

You will see that it gives an error.

However, it then has an additional piece of code which checks if there is a required option.  If so, is will perform an additional search for options to satisfy this even if there is a space between the flag and argument.

Hint for looking at the code: has_arg is an enum with 0=No argument 1=Required arguemnt 2=Optional argument

### Short Answer

libargtable will not process optional arguments if there is a space between the flag and the argument.  Remove the space and it should work.

I might consider this a bug, but perhaps some people like this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that `./argbug -oother.txt` would work and thought it was an error in the underlying getopt. I reported this to Steward but we're both working on our PhDs and have no time to do anything about it.

Comment: I'm guessing that the getopt authors would consider it a feature, not a bug.